# How to write the signature of a method that receives a general Object

Tags: java, object

Suppose that I have these two objects:

```
Color c = new Color();
Shape s = new Shape();
```

and a method run() with some signature.

Now suppose that I want to call the run method sometimes with an object color and sometimes with an object shape. I could do something like these:

```
run(c);
public void( Color c){
     //a bunch of code
}
```

or something like these:

```
run(s);
public void( Shape s){
     //a bunch of code
}
```

As you can see, this is a bad solution because I'm creating the same method again but with different signatures and repeating a bunch of code 2 times. Is there any way to pass a generic object do this run method and then work with it? And of course no repeating code?

Comment: Do Shape and Color share an ancestor? Implement an interface? Otherwise, I am not certain how is the "a bunch of code" going to be in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All  objects in java extend (at the end) java.lang.Object class.

So, if you want a "*generic*" method, you should write something like:

```
public void methodName(Object o) {
...
}
```

But, make sure to make a casting accordingly inside this method.

You can use something like:

```
if (o instanceof Shape) {
    Shape s = (Shape) o;
} else if (o instanceof Color) {
    Color c = (Color) o
}
```

There are other options, for example passing an interface as a parameter of the method, and both classes should implement that interface.

Comment: That's it. Awesome fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Object class.

Every object has inheritance from the Object class, which means every object is a member of the object class.

If your method signature asks for an Object, then any object will be valid.

```
public void( Object o) {
// some code
}
```

Both shape and color are objects, so both will fit this method signature.

Comment: Of course, this answer is true, but there is no way to execute particular methods of Shape or Color when one accepts an Object. One could take an Object and then do an `instanceof` to handle particular questions, but that approach is very maintenance unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1. create a common interface of the objects and define the function with it:

```
public void run(CommonInterface c)
```

2. Accept `Object` as a parameter:

```
public void run(Object o)
```

Comment: These approaches are not almost the same. The first one allows executing the methods of the `interface CommonInterface` on the passed object `c`. The second one gives one only an Object, and therefore only the methods available on the Object class unless one writes code to find the specific type.

Answer (score 0):

The question that is asked is inviting very specific answers. As others have noted, if there is an interface that both objects can implement, that is the best approach. One can accept an Object as a parameter, and then (potentially) ascertain the type. However, this question is slightly problematic because it is not describing the actual desired result. It is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What happens when one then has a Texture object? Adjusting the code to continually deal with new types that do not implement a common interface will drive the maintenance costs very high. Therefore, one needs to look at the overall design. More than likely, the solution is that the run() should be implemented on each Object, and not be a method that takes the various object types directly.

As much as I do not really like the book, the maintenance example presented by this question is well described in *Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design*.

Answer (score 0):

I think what matters here is what it is you want to do in `// A bunch of code`. For example, if you want to call `.toString()` method of `Object`, then you can pass object, but if you wish to do more than that, then you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think below example will be able to help you.

interface I {}

class A implements I {}

class B implements I {}

class Demo`{`

public static void main(String []args){

Demo d=new Demo();

```
 d.run(new A());
 d.run(new B());
```

}

public `<`T extends I`>` void run(T t)`{`

```
      // TODO do here you logic


 }
```

}